# Remove Character Occurrences Until the First Different One, Java

Tags: java, string, methods

So I have some numerical strings like the following ones:

"00000545468" - "00002021" - "000000001990" etc.. (I don't know how this strings will be passed to me, the only thing I know is that they will start with some zeros from left and then there will be other different numbers)

I want to remove all the zeros (0) occurrences **from left** until the first different number of the string.
So if I have for example "00002021", I want to have as a result "2021" and if I have "000000001990" I want "1990".

I excluded the usage of **.replace("0", "")**, because by doing this I would also remove the zero in "2021" and in "1990", and I don't want this to happen.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [replaceFirst](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceFirst(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) or [replaceAll](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) but the main point is to *anchor* your regex so it will only replace the zeroes if they are placed at the begining of the string.

```
"00002021".replaceFirst("^0+", "")
```

should return what you need, and does not replace zeroes if they are not at the beginning of the string.

You can check this at https://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html (disclaimer: I do not own this website and I do not profit by linking to it).

Comment: Thank you so much, this worked fine :)